# The image of the inverse of a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity

First of all I'm not sure if my title is correct with the question, I find it hard to really get about what kind of set this question is about. It would be very helpful if someone could explain this to me.

Let $n,m \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$ and $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be a continuous function. For every $c \in \mathbb{R}^m$ we define the following set:

$$ f^{-1}(c)=\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n | f(x) =c \} $$

a) Give an epsilon - delta proof to show that every finite intersection of closed set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is again closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$

b) Proof for $m \geq 1$ that the set $f^{-1}(c)$ is a closed part of $\mathbb{R}^n$. (hint: first proof if for $m=1$ and then use part a))

c) Show that the set $D \in \mathbb{R}^3$ given by:
$$ D := \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3| x^2 + y^2 = 1 \  \mathrm{ and } \ x+y+z=1 $$
is closed.

I think I answered question a correctly:

Suppose we have $A = \cap_{i=1}^{n} A_i$, with $A_i$ is closed for every $1 \leq i \leq n$. Now we take $x$ as a limitpoint of $A$. Thus for every $\delta >0, B(x,\delta) \cap A \neq \emptyset$ so we can take an element, say $y$ in this set. For this $y$ we thus know that $y\in A = \cap A_i$ and thus $y\in B(x,\delta) \cap A_i$ for every $i$. Thus x is a limitpoint of $A_i$ and because $A_i$ is closed we get $x \in A_i$ this holds for every $i$ thus $ x\in \cap A_i =A$ thus $A$ is closed.

With question b) I tried to answer it using the fact that f is continuous but I can't get the hang of it. I get confused by which limit I would need to take because of this inverse and the set which all become rather confusing. I tried to use sort of the same proof as in a) by taking a y in the closure of $f^{-1}$ and to proof that it's also in $f$

It would be great if some could give me some hints on how to start with this question properly.

Comment: Your solution of (a) looks good. For the other two parts you may find the topological characterization of continuity useful: $f$ is continuous if and only if the preimage, i.e. $f^{-1}(U)$, of every open set $U$ is again open. This can be restated by replacing open by closed, and sets containing one point only are closed in your example.

Comment: Hmm so you would use the fact that a closed set is a set whose complement is open? I don't really see how this proof should be, could you give a little more details?

Comment: First of all, do you know the result that "f is continuous iff preimages of open sets are open"? If not, you can look it up literally everywhere and you should have no problem following the proof. Given this result, yes - you use the complement thing: If C is closed in $\mathbb{R}^m$, then $\mathbb{R}^m\backslash C$ is open, so $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^m\backslash C)$ is open. But this is precisely $=\ldots = \mathbb{R}^n\backslash f^{-1}(C)$, so $f^{-1}(C)$ is closed. Now apply this to the 1-point set $C=\{c\}$. This isn't necessarily the only solution here, but a very convenient one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us take $m=1$. To prove that $f^{-1}(c)$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$, we may consider any sequence $\{x_k\}_k$ of points in $f^{-1}(c)$ such that $x_k \to x$ as $k \to +\infty$. Our task is to prove that $x \in f^{-1}(c)$, i.e. $f(x)=c$.

Now, for each $k$ we have $f(x_k)=c$. Letting $k \to +\infty$ and using the continuity of $f$ we deduce that $f(x)=\lim_k f(x_k) = \lim_k c = c$.

Comment: How does this proof show that if $x$ is in the closure of $f^{-1}$ then it's also in $f^{-1}$

Comment: Read: $f(x)=c$.

Comment: Well I see that you have shown that $f(x)=c$, which I understand to be relevant. But I don't see where you have shown that this holds for all limitpoints. I don't see the place where you start with suppose $x$ is in the closure of $f_{-1}$

Comment: A point is in the closure if and only if it is the limit of a sequence of points from the set.

Comment: Can you also help me with proving this for $m\geq 1$. What I thought of was the following. Let $  m \geq 1$ be arbitrary. Now we have the function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ which we can write in the following way $f= (f_1, ...  f_m)$. We now define the function $g_i$ with $1 \leq i \leq m$ as follows $g_i : \mathbb{R}^n  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto f_i(x)$. Now we have  m functions to which the statement holds and we can use a). But I think this is totally wrong